# LinkedIn Bulk invitation with personalized name

Tags: linkedin-api

Just wondering is there a way to personalize the invitation with individual name.

example: `Dear {Name}`,

I have some 2800+ contact lists in my LinkedIn account, and i would like to invite all of them to a group, but with a personalized message as explained above.
...